# if $G_{4n+1}=2G_{2n+1}-G_{n},G_{4n+3}=3G_{2n+1}-2G_{n}$,Find $G_{n}=n?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> let sequence $\{G_{n}\}$ such
>   $$G_{1}=1,G_{3}=3,G_{2n}=G_{n}$$
>   $$G_{4n+1}=2G_{2n+1}-G_{n},G_{4n+3}=3G_{2n+1}-2G_{n}$$

If such $G_{n}=n$, then we said $n$ is 'good'.
How many 'good' numbers $n$, such that $n<2^{100}?$

**My try:**

since
$$\begin{eqnarray}G_{1}&=&1,\\
G_{2}&=&1,\\
G_{3}&=&3,\\
G_{4}&=&G_{2}=1\\
G_{5}&=&2G_{3}-G_{1}=5,\\
G_{6}&=&G_{3}=3,\\
G_{7}&=&3G_{3}-2G_{1}=9-2=7\\
G_{8}&=&G_{4}=1,\\
G_{9}&=&2G_{5}-G_{2}=10-1=9,\\
G_{10}&=&G_{5}=5,\\
G_{11}&=&3G_{5}-2G_{2}=15-2=13,
G_{12}&=&G_{6}=3,\\
G_{13}&=&2G_{7}-G_{3}=14-3=11,\\
G_{14}&=&G_{7}=7,\\
G_{15}&=&3G_{7}-2G_{3}=21-6=15,\end{eqnarray}$$

so when $n=1,3,5,7,9,,15,\cdots$ is 'good"

But How find numbers? when $n<2^{100}?$

Thank you

Comment: $G_2 = G_1 = 1$, so $G_2$ is not good.

Comment: I made a program. There are $2,2,4,4,8,8, ...$ good numbers between $4$ and $8$, $8$ and $16$, $16$ and $32$, $32$ and $64$, $64$ and $128$, $128$ and $256$ ...

Comment: Can we get a confirmation on the value of $G_2$? $G_2=1$ is more elegant. Then the pattern of this sequence goes: For $n=2^k$ to $n = 2^{k+1}-1$ we have the odd numbers $1,3,...,2^{k+1}-1$ in a particular order. For $n=2^{k+1}$ to $n = 2^{k+2}-1$ the next sequence of odd numbers is built from the old by inserting $2^{k+1}+1$ after $1$, $2^{k+1}+3$ after $3$, $2^{k+1}+5$ after $5$, etc. Hence $1 \rightarrow 1,3 \rightarrow 1,5,3,7 \rightarrow 1,9,5,13,3,11,7,15$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is sequence [A030101](http://oeis.org/A030101) in the OEIS.  That is, $G(n)$ is the number obtained by reversing the digits of $n$ when written base $2$, e.g. $G(25)=G(11001_2)=10011_2=19$.

This is easy to check:  If $n=d_0+2d_1+\cdots+2^rd_r$, then

$$
\begin{align}
G(n)&=d_r+\cdots+2^rd_0\\
G(2n)&=d_r+\cdots+2^rd_0+2^{r+1}\cdot0\\
G(2n+1)&=d_r+\cdots+2^rd_0+2^{r+1}\cdot1\\
G(4n+1)&=d_r+\cdots+2^rd_0+2^{r+1}\cdot0+2^{r+2}\cdot1\\
G(4n+3)&=d_r+\cdots+2^rd_0+2^{r+1}\cdot1+2^{r+2}\cdot1
\end{align}
$$

from which the identities $G(2n)=G(n)$, $G(4n+1)=2G(2n+1)-G(n)$, and $G(4n+3)=3G(2n+1)-2G(n)$ are easily verified.

The upshot is that the OP's "good" numbers are those that are palindromes when written in binary.

Answer (score 1):

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n$ can be written uniquely in the form $\sum_{j=0}^{m} a_j 2^j$ with $a_j \in \{0, 1\}$ for $j=0,1,...,m-1$ and $a_m = 1$

Now for $n = \sum_{j=0}^{m} a_j 2^j$ with $a_j \in \{0, 1\}$ for $j=0,1,...,m-1$ and $a_m = 1$,

define

$f(n) = \sum_{j=0}^{m} a_{m-j} 2^j$

then

$f(1) = f(1 * 2^0) = 1 * 2^0 = 1$

$f(2) = f(1 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^0) = 0 * 2^1 + 1 * 2^0 = 1$

$f(3) = f(1 * 2^1 + 1 * 2^0) = 1 * 2^1 + 1 * 2^0 = 3$

and

\begin{align}
f(2 n) & = f(0 * 2^0 + a_0  * 2^1 + a_1 * 2^2 + ... + a_m * 2^{m+1})\\ 
 & = a_m * 2^0 + a_{m-1} * 2^1 + ... + a_0 * 2^m + 0 * 2^{m+1}\\ 
 & = f(a_0 * 2^0 + a_1 * 2^1 + ... + a_m * 2^m) + 0 * 2^{m+1}\\ 
 & = f(n)\\
 & \\
f(4 n + 1) & = f(1 * 2^0 + 0 * 2^1 + a_0 * 2^3 + a_1 * 2^4 + ... + a_m * 2^{m+2})\\ 
 & = a_m * 2^0 + a_{m-1} * 2^1 + ... + a_0 * 2^m + 0 * 2^{m+1} + 1 * 2^{m+2}\\ 
 & = (2-1) * (a_m * 2^0 + a_{m-1} * 2^1 + ... + a_0 * 2^m) + 2 * 2^{m+1}\\ 
& = 2 (a_m * 2^0 + a_{m-1} * 2^1 +...+ a_0 * 2^m + 1 * 2^{m+1})- (a_m * 2^0 + a_{m-1} * 2^1 + ... + a_0 * 2^m)\\
& = 2 f(1 * 2^0 + a_0 * 2^1 + a_1 * 2^2 + ... + a_m * 2^{m+1})- f(a_0 * 2^0 + a_1 * 2^1 + ... + a_m * 2^m)\\
 & = 2 f(2n+1) - f(n)\\
 & \\
f(4 n + 3) & = f(1 * 2^0 + 1 * 2^1 + a_0 * 2^3 + a_1 * 2^4 + ... + a_m * 2^{m+2})\\ 
 & = a_m * 2^0 + a_{m-1} * 2^1 + ... + a_0 * 2^m + 1 * 2^{m+1} + 1 * 2^{m+2}\\ 
 & = (3-2) * (a_m * 2^0 + a_{m-1} * 2^1 + ... + a_0 * 2^m) + 3 * 2^{m+1}\\
& = 3(a_m * 2^0 + a_{m-1} * 2^1 +...+ a_0 * 2^m + 1 * 2^{m+1})-2 (a_m * 2^0 + a_{m-1} * 2^1 + ... + a_0 * 2^m)\\
& = 3 f(1 * 2^0 + a_0 * 2^1 + a_1 * 2^2 + ... + a_m * 2^{m+1})- 2 f(a_0 * 2^0 + a_1 * 2^1 + ... + a_m * 2^m)\\
 & = 3 f(2n+1) - 2 f(n)\end{align}

It follows by induction $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, G_n = f(n) $, that is $G_n$ is the number obtained by reversing the order of the binary digits of $n$ and a *good* number is a number with a symmetric representation in binary.

Now the first binary digit of any number must be a $1$ so a *good* number must also end with a $1$.

If $n$ has an odd number, $2k+1$, binary digits then for symmetry we have $k$ choices and $2^k$ ways of choosing the internal digits of n.

If $n$ has an even number, $2k+2$, binary digits then for symmetry we have $k$ choices and $2^k$ ways of choosing the internal digits of n.

Hence the the number of *good* numbers < $2^{100}$ (with $100$ or less binary digits) is

$1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 4 + ... + 2^{49} + 2^{49} = 2 * (2^{50} - 1)$

Comment: We're like binary twins!

Comment: I was just proofreading mine when yours came up. Seemed a shame not to post it. :)